# Old movie where a portal suddenly opens in a street in front of a girl and she trades places with her parallel self

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

The movie has a girl who is walking down the street, suddenly some portal/door to parallel earth is opened. She chases her hat (or some paper) which goes into the door.

She finds her parallel self and they both exchange places for a day until the door closes permanently.

It's more of a fantasy rather than a horror. I think this may be an old movie or show, but I have this memory of seeing this when I was little.

Comment: “I have this memory of seeing this when I was little” — when were you little? That might help narrow down what movie this is.

Comment: You say it's an old movie and you watch it when you was little? Roughly how long ago was that and how old would the movie be? Can you remember anything that happens when they exchange places? Do they end up swapping back again? _"It's more of a fantasy rather than a horror."_ What makes you say it might be a horror? If you can remember anything else about this please don't hesitate to [edit] extra details into your question.